# Deja-dup "Restore failed - no backups to restore" after clean install of Ubuntu

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I have a serious problem.

Earlier today I had to make a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10 on my private computer. I'd hoped that I could easily access the (encrypted) backups I've earlier made with the Deja-dup Backup tool on my external hard drive. However, I now get the error message that the "restore failed" because there are "no backups to restore", although I do see the relevant `.difftar.gpg` files in Nautilus.

I've tried using the command line

```
duplicity restore file:///path_to_folder_contains_backups/ path_where_to_extract_it/
```

but get the error message:

```
CollectionsError: No backup chains found
```

Running

```
sudo duplicity collection-status file:/path/to/file
```

returns that there is 1 secondary backup chain and 1 primary backup chain with a matching signature chain. However, it also throws a gpg WARNING: "unsafe ownership on homedir '/path/to/my/homedirectory/.gnupg'". Checking the permissions on /.gnupg gives

```
drwx------ 3 username username 4096 Apr 21 16:00 .
```

for the directory and this for the files inside:

```
-rw------- 1 username username   43 Apr 21 16:00 gpg-agent.conf
-rw------- 1 username username  258 Apr 21 16:00 gpg.conf
drwx------ 2 username username 4096 Apr 21 13:25 private-keys-v1.d
-rw------- 1 username username   32 Apr 21 14:02 pubring.kbx
-rw------- 1 username username 1200 Apr 21 14:02 trustdb.gpg
```

The directory `/private-keys-v1` is empty.

I would greatly appreciate any help since I have lost access to all my private files.

Comment: Had you ever restored from a backup before you did the install? In other words, did it used to work?

Comment: No, since there was no need for a restore while everything worked fine.

Comment: You can get some information on the problem by doing the command `sudo duplicity collection-status file://[location of your backup directory]`  I suggest you do that and edit the results into your question.  It may just repeat the CollectionsError you already got though.

Comment: The command returns that it has "found 1 secondary backup chain" and "Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:".

Comment: Have you imported the gpg keys after reinstall?

Comment: Which gpg keys does Deja-dup use? Where could I find them?

Comment: Well that's good news with the `collection-status` result, your backup is OK, we  just need to get deja-dup to acknowledge it.

Comment: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2003-October/020342.html

Comment: I've added the permissions on the /.gnupg directory in the question.

Comment: Something to try that may work, add more info, or just give you the same error: `deja-dup --restore /path/filename` in a terminal.  If this works, it pops up the Backups dialog and asks you to choose the backup location, etc.  Just pick any file you know the name & location of, for a test.

Comment: FYI if you can't get it to work any other way, all is not lost, as long as the backup data is OK you can restore the backup without deja-dup like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/793135/how-to-restore-a-broken-deja-dup-backup-manually?rq=1 although it isn't pretty.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions - you've definitely put me on the right lead. What seems to be working now is this: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be working for me (the recovery is currently halfway through) was the command

```
duplicity --gio file:///media/backup /tmp/restore
```

where I've replaced *media/backup* and */tmp/restore* with the filepath to the backups and my recovery destination, respectively. After entering the GNUpg passphrase I've chosen when setting up the backups in Deja-dup, the recovery process started.

For more detailed information please refer to [this guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase).

Comment: That's a useful guide, thanks for the link.  Glad it's working.