# DejaDup "Restore Failed, no backups to restore"

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

after recently having issues with my Ubuntu installation, I live booted Ubuntu, mounted the problematic partition, and made a complete backup of it using Deja Dup. However, upon wiping that partition and reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04, it won't let me restore my backup.

All necessary files (manifest and signature) seem to be present. When attempting to restore with Deja Dup, it simply gives a generic "Restore Failed, no backups to restore" error. When attempting to restore using duplicity in command line, I get the error `duplicity.dup_collections.CollectionsError: No backup chains found`. Investigating further using
`duplicity collection-status`, it says

```
No backup chains with active signatures found
Also found 1 backup set not part of any chain,
and 0 incomplete backup sets.
```

I don't have any reason to believe my backup has become corrupted, but I cannot restore it. Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I just fired up the Backup utility, and tried to restore an old backup, and I get a similar message.  The system says 'No backups to restore'.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well.

Comment: Perhaps of note is the fact that the partition I backed up was Ubuntu 18.04, not 20.04.

Comment: I'm gonna try a restore from an 18.04 backup set to a 20.04 machine, will report back.

Comment: I just successfully restored a file with `deja-dup --restore test.txt` from a backup taken on an 18.04 system to a (beta test) 21.04 system. So I don't think it's just the version difference unfortunately.  I also got a normal output when I did a `collection-status`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution; first check to see if the backup is valid:

[Deja-dup "Restore failed - no backups to restore" after clean install of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026928/deja-dup-restore-failed-no-backups-to-restore-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu)

The key command by *Organic Marble* is here:

```
sudo duplicity collection-status file://[location of your backup directory]
```

So, for me, to restore, I had to select the 'Local Folder' option, and select the backup directory that was valid via that command above.

I'm using Backup (the gui).   This was a bit scary, as I hadn't changed anything for backing up, and the normal option that I used to backup said "New backup..." when this was an incremental backup.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has been a bit quirky, to say the least...

Comment: Using the --gio command returns "Will not overwrite". And yup, I've tried using DejaDup with the same filepath as I used for the output above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what this error was from exactly, but I used [this guide from DejaDup](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase#Restoring_by_Hand) to restore everything by hand, which mostly worked, albeit with some weirdly corrupted files.