# Deja-Dup, Duplicity: 31 GPGError, decryption failed: Bad session key

Tags: backup, gnupg, deja-dup, duplicity

I'm using Deja-Dup for years to backup my desktop system to a local NAS. A while ago it stopped working. I tried using a new, clean destination folder on the NAS as well as numerous hints from the web, all without success.

```
DUPLICITY: . GPG error detail: Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1414, in do_backup
DUPLICITY: .     sync_archive()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1204, in sync_archive
DUPLICITY: .     copy_to_local(fn)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1150, in copy_to_local
DUPLICITY: .     copy_raw(src_iter, tdp.name)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1068, in copy_raw
DUPLICITY: .     data = src_iter.next().data
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1132, in next
DUPLICITY: .     self.fileobj.close()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_temp.py", line 227, in close
DUPLICITY: .     assert not self.fileobj.close()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 305, in close
DUPLICITY: .     self.gpg_failed()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 272, in gpg_failed
DUPLICITY: .     raise GPGError(msg)
DUPLICITY: .  GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
DUPLICITY: . gpg: AES256 encrypted data
DUPLICITY: . gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
DUPLICITY: . gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . 
DUPLICITY: . 

DUPLICITY: ERROR 31 GPGError
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
DUPLICITY: . gpg: AES256 encrypted data
DUPLICITY: . gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
DUPLICITY: . gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: .
```

I use Ubuntu Linux 18.04 with Deja-Dup 37.1, Duplicity 0.7.17 and GnuPG 2.2.4.

Comment: Looks like a bug...  Please [file one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup)

Comment: probably this issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057627/duplicity-fails-with-bad-session-key-error ..ede/duply.net

Comment: I'm running into the same error.  I've tried the workaround posted in the link in the comment by @ede but it didn't work in my case.  Had a hard drive failure, had to reinstall Ubuntu, so I'm trying to restore from my backup.  Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: I wonder if we are both encountering this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1828761